# AngularJS - Access child directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

How to access the child directive controllers?
Specifically, I need to access all ngModelController(s) which are present inside a parent directive.
Example:

```html
<parent-directive>
  <input type="text" ng-model="model1"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="model2"/>
</parent-directive>
```

So, is there a way for "parentDirective" to get access to the ngModelControllers for "model1" and "model2"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**

jqLite [extras methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods) also has a controller method to retrieve the specific controller associated to the element. So you can query for the ng-models and get the controller name as `angular.element(el).controller('ngModel')` as well.

> controller(name) - retrieves the controller of the current element or its parent. By default retrieves controller associated with the ngController directive. If name is provided as camelCase directive name, then the controller for this directive will be retrieved (e.g. 'ngModel').

---

angular also places the controller associated with an element on its data. Similarly ngModel controller instance associated with the directive is accessibly via `$ngModelController`. So you could actually access it and use the ngModel instance to do whatever you are doing.  However this is completely a non standard way of doing it, because `$ngModelController` is undocumented and there is no guarantee the implementation will not change in future versions.

An example implementation:

```
.directive('parentDirective', function($timeout){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    link:function(scope, elm){
      /*Get the elements with the attribute ng-model, in your case this could just be elm.children()*/
      var elms = [].slice.call(elm[0].querySelectorAll('[ng-model]'), 0);

      /*get the ngModelControllerArray*/
      var controllers = elms.map(function(el){ 
          return angular.element(el).controller('ngModel');
          //return angular.element(el).data('$ngModelController');
      });

       /*As a sample implementation i am registering a view value listener for these controller instances*/
       controllers.forEach(function(ngModel){
         ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(logViewChange.bind(null, ngModel));
       });

       function logViewChange(ngModel){
           console.log(ngModel.$name, ngModel.$viewValue);
       }
    }
  }
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/v3eGpSOFvt7UCQT3llYv?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your commitment. This is the solution. The crutial part is "return angular.element(el).data('$ngModelController');". This line could be written as follows too "return angular.element(el).controllwe('ngModel');". Link to your Plnkr with that modification http://plnkr.co/edit/shn6978dFkH3YFfkUnRy?p=preview

Comment: Oh yes i actually had forgotted about the jqlite extras on this. Thanks. I will update my answer.